# Is there a way to create a RollingFileAppender programatically?

Tags: java, logback, slf4j, java-platform-module-system

I am trying to create a logger and appender for my project but it needs to be configurable so i was thinking of setting it programatically.

The problem is when i try to import "import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender;"

but it is throwing me an error of: 
"The type ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender is not accessible"

The strange part is that in the line i am using the RollingFileAppender class it is recommending me this same import.

I have logback-classic-1.3.0-alpha4.jar and logback-core-1.3.0-alpha4.jar in the modulepath and the module-info.jar is:

```
module tool.foo {
    requires com.fazecast.jSerialComm;
    requires commons.cli;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires java.xml;
    requires java.naming;
    requires java.net.http;
    requires org.slf4j;
    requires swt;
    requires ch.qos.logback.core;
    requires ch.qos.logback.classic;

    requires static org.junit.jupiter.api;
    requires static org.junit.jupiter.params;
    requires static org.junit.jupiter.engine;

    exports com.enterprise.tools.foo;
}
```

The class looks like this:

```
package com.premium.tools.pamtool.controller;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender;

public class CsvLogger {

    public static Logger createLoggerFor(String file) {
        LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        PatternLayoutEncoder ple = new PatternLayoutEncoder();

        ple.setPattern("%msg");
        ple.setContext(lc);
        ple.start();
        RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
        fileAppender.setFile(file);
        fileAppender.setEncoder(ple);
        fileAppender.setContext(lc);
        fileAppender.setAppend(false);
        fileAppender.start();

        Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("CsvLogger");
        logger.addAppender(fileAppender);
        logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        logger.setAdditive(false); /* set to true if root should log too */
        return logger;
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, which library do you want to use [slf4j](https://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html) or [logback](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html) ?

Comment: I would prefer to use slf4j because if we ever need to migrate to another logging implementation it would be easier. But i could not find any information about creating a rollingFileAppender programmatically in slf4j

Comment: Try to add [that](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.17) in your pom or as a library. I added that bundle into my project and no errors occur with line `RollingFileAppender appender=new RollingFileAppender();`

Comment: That would be a really valid option in java < 9. But as of now i am using java 11 with the new modules system which allows me to create a modularized java image so log4j is not an option (it is not supported yet). Anyway, i have looked through the source code of the logback project on github and found they don't export the ch.qos.logback.core.rolling module. I opened an improvement: https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1463